# Wrong projection used in Pathfinder

Tags: coordinate-system, trimble, pathfinder, post-processing

I am having issues with coordinate systems in post processing. Does anyone have a recommendation of videos to watch or online classes that can help me improve on this? This is my current issue: Data was taken in the field using UTM, 16 North, using NAD 1983 (Conus). When I export it using Pathfinder I choose to Use Export Coordinate System using Projected Coordinate System NAD 1983 UTM Zone 16N. When I open it in ArcMap it is no where near where it should be. I know this is probably super simple but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Where does the data show up? I would suspect that the data came into Pathfinder as degrees rather than UTM coordinates and were labeled wrong or something similar.

Comment: I found my issue, I needed to change the Export Coordinate System, I didn't have it on the right Export Coordinate System - I didn't choose NAD 1983 (Conus). Thanks for your help.